# Comparing a user input string to a line from a text file in c creates infinite loop

Tags: c, string, text-files

I'm trying to get better at coding in general and C in particular, and am coding a small text adventure game. I read a string input by the user i.e LOOK room and compare it to a txt file with the list of commands for that particular section.

As I am reading from the text file I have a counter which keeps track of which line is being read, when the match is made I convert the line number to a character and concatenate it to "outside.txt" so that when the correct command is input it will read from the correct file i.e LOOK room would load text from 1outside.txt etc.

However, when inputting anything it just loops on "I dont understand" forever. Any explanation as to why or constructive comments on my code are appreciated, especially if I am misunderstanding how files and/or strings in c.

```
    int mansionOutside(void)
    {
        int stop = 1;
        char choice[25];
        char word_match[25];
        char text_line[73];
        char line1[25];
        char temp[2];
        int counter;
        FILE *fptr;
        fptr = fopen("mansion_commands.txt", "r");
        if (fptr == NULL)
        {
            printf("ERROR!");
        }
        else
        {
            while (stop == 1)
            {   
                printf("\n");
                fgets(choice, sizeof choice, stdin);

                while (fgets (line1, 25, fptr)!= NULL)
                {
                    if (strcmp(line1, choice) == 0)
                    {
                        printf("%s\n", line1);
                        stop = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        counter++;
                        printf("%s + %s\n", line1, choice);
                    }
                }

                if  (stop == 1)
                {
                    printf("I dont understand\n");
                    counter = 1;
                }
            }
            fclose(fptr);
            counter = counter + '0';
            temp[0] = counter;
            temp[1] = '\0';

            strncat(word_match, temp , 1);
            strcat(word_match, ".txt");

            fptr = fopen(word_match, "r");
            if (fptr == NULL)
            {
                printf("ERROR!\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Debugging : File opened Successfully\n");

                while (fgets (text_line, 72, fptr) != NULL)
                {
                    printf("%s", text_line);
                    //delay(2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT : Took in suggestions for improvements to avoid Buffer overflows such as using > fgets , but I think there is something I have missed. Now If I input anything contained in the file, it works fine. If however I input something wrong, then something correct on re-prompt, It skips the inner while loop all together and goes straight to "I don't understand".
The following is what happens when my input is LOOK room, and then LOOK mansion.

[image: sampledebugginh]

Comment: Use the simple debugging technique of printing out intermediate results. This `choice[strlen(choice) - 1] = '\0';`, for example, is suspect – it seems you want it to remove the `\n` at the end, but are you sure there is one? (Which in fact cause your next problem.) Similar, `fgets` (famously *and* documented) **leaves** the `\n` at the end.

Comment: I used fgets and removed the whole choice[strlen] line, now the problem is that if I input anything that isnt the first line in the file, whilst the two lines are printed as identical, it loops again to fgets, and If I input something incorrect, then Input the first line, then it doesnt work either. Im guessing some corruption in memory?

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%[^\n]s", choice);`  This will NOT work as desired.  The main reason is the call to `scanf()` will terminate input when it encounters a newline ('\n') in the input, so the next char in the input is NEVER 's'.  So start by removing that trailing 's' from the format string

Comment: the posted code: 1) is missing the needed include statements for `stdio.h` and `string.h`  2) the compiler outputs the message: `warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]` which definitely needs to be corrected

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("ERROR!");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  and when the error is from a C library function, Then should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  A simple way to do this is to call `perror( "my error message" );`

Comment: when the call to `fopen()` fails, then should output a error message to `stderr` and then call `exit()`, not continue to execute the program

Comment: regarding: `printf("\n");`  The function `printf()` is very expensive in CPU cycles,  Suggest using: `puts("");`

Comment: regarding; `while (fgets (line1, 25, fptr)!= NULL)
                {
                    if (strcmp(line1, choice) == 0)`  the buffer `line1[]` will be terminated with a '\n' (a newline).  What is the lines in `mansion_commands.txt` terminated with?  if not a newline, then should remove the newline from `choice[]`  perhaps via: `choice[ strcspn( choice, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`  Otherwise the two strings will never compare equal and they will not compare equal if they contain different spacing

Comment: every line in mansion_commands.txt is terminated with a new line, I even added a blank new line at the end so the last command would work. The problem is that whilst I can input any correct line and it works, if I input the wrong line, then it doesnt work when I input the correct one again.

Comment: okay its all okay now, the problem was caused by the file pointer pointing to the EOF character at the end of the file after the first set of comparisons, then not resetting, reset it at If stop == 1  and it now works perfectly, thank you all for your time